# How do I get the value of array of object by using aggregate pipleline in Mongodb with Java syntax

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the array of Oject value but it is giving empty value .I need get the  **result**
Value from the below document .

**Email Systems-->result**

```
 { 

"_id" : ObjectId("5f0890e870e631865877e"), 

"user" : "testuser", 
"Email" : "testuser@sample.com", 
"Batch Systems" : [
    "STAR", 
    "STORY", 
    "ITEMS", 
    
   
], 
"Email Systems" : [
    {
        "System1" : {
            "System" : "Backend", 
            **"result"** : true
        }
    }, 
    {
       "System2" : {
            "System" : "Backend", 
            "result" : true
        }
    }
],
```

Below is snippet of code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getClaimsBySearchCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId){
    MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(test);
    MongoCollection<Document> users = database.getCollection(Systems);
     List<? extends Bson> pipelinesVal = Arrays.asList(
                new Document()
                        .append("$unwind", "$Email Systems"),
                new Document()
                        .append("$match",  new Document().append("Email Systems","$Email Systems")),
                new Document()
                        .append("$project", new Document()
                                .append("_id", 1)
                                .append("items", 1)

                        ));
        List<Document> Val = new ArrayList<>();
        List values=users.aggregate(pipelinesVal).into(Val);
        Document docSourceSystem =new Document();
        List<Document> aggregate = new ArrayList<>();
        LOG.info("pipelinesVal: " + pipelinesVal.toString());
       LOG.info("values: " + values.toString());
}
```

With the above code result value is coming as empty instead of true or false .Can anybody help me with the issue .what is going wrong with the above code

Comment: why do you have `space` in keys like **Batch Systems**,***Email Systems**?

Comment: In mongodb database keys are defined like Batch Systems , Email Systems , So we cannot change the keys value